# How can I get started and write code in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I am a .Net developer but recently shifted to PHP world. I have worked with PHP in the past and written code in CodeIgniter and core PHP. I understand all of that.

But currently we have a Joomla requirement. I did go through Joomla getting started and also went through these video tutorials: 
http://www.buildajoomlawebsite.com/joomla-tutorials/the-basics/

But they just teach where to move mouse and what to click etc. I can't find any code in there. I have a project coming and so I am sure there has to be some way where we can actually open something in editor and write CODE!

I need to integrate Paypal IPN also in that website. But I am totally stuck. I just can't find where do I write some code. How do I get started with all these? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I'd get to grip with Templates, because these control the look of the website and are easy to understand. Just modify the default template to see how things work.

http://docs.joomla.org/Template_Development

Before starting developing your own modules or components, it's always worth checking what's out there already because you'll often find something that's close to what you're trying to do so you can learn or modify existing solutions:

http://extensions.joomla.org/

The next step in development would be writing a module, which can be displayed in any position on the website.

http://docs.joomla.org/Module_Development

If you need to do more than display information on the front end it's time to look at writing a component:

http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development

Comment: Great! It has some links to MVC development etc. I think it is exactly what I am looking for! I will now proceed in the same exact way that you have listed the links.

Comment: Hope you enjoy working with Joomla! Just to reiterate: my first port of call would be a quick search on extensions.joomla.org (listings are required to be licensed under the GPL so you're free to use code under those terms and the reviews provide some indication of quality).